# HA Master Node for K8s Cluster in Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, kubernetes

I somehow managed to initialize a master node using the kubeadm tool on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. I now want to have HA for the master node. Upon successful set up of the master node, I can see towards the end of the console that there was a join command from the kubeadm. The information next to it states that I should run this join command from all the worker nodes so that they join my master node.

This is fine, but how can I set up another master node and make this master node aware of the one that I have already set up? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you follow (and adapt) the [Creating HA clusters with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/) guide:

> This guide shows you how to install and set up a highly available Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm.
>
> This document shows you how to perform setup tasks that kubeadm doesn’t perform: provision hardware; configure multiple systems; and load balancing.
>
> **Note:** This guide is only one potential solution, and there are many ways to configure a highly available cluster. If a better solution works for you, please use it. If you find a better solution that can be adopted by the community, feel free to contribute it back.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this documentation from the official Kubernetes documentation pages:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#installing-prerequisites-on-masters

Looks like it is a bit of work with the kuberadm to set up HA master / etcd.